# Count number of files on FTP server

Tags: ssis, ftp, winscp

How do I count number of zip files present in an FTP folder in SSIS?

Guide me to find the number of files present.

Answer (score 1):

With the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), just use the [`Session.EnumerateRemoteFiles` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_enumerateremotefiles) and call the [`Count` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count#system-linq-enumerable-count-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) on the result:

```csharp
var path = "/remote/path";
var files = session.EnumerateRemoteFiles(path, "*.zip", EnumerationOptions.None);
int count = files.Count();
```

---

See also [Using WinSCP .NET Assembly from SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).